# Canot interfer type: TreeSet<int[]> with lambda Comparator

Tags: java, arrays, int

I have tried a few things and i don't understand why it is not working.

I'm creating a SortedSet and like to use a TreeSet as the implementation with an lambda expression comparator:

```
SortedSet<int[]> all = new TreeSet<>(
        (int[] a, int[] b) -> { return (a[0] == b[0]) ? a[1] >= b[1] : a[0] >= b[0]; }
    );


SortedSet<int[]> all = new TreeSet<>(
        (a, b) -> (a[0] == b[0]) ? a[1] >= b[1] : a[0] >= b[0]
    );
```

Whatever version i tried, it just doesn't work and i don't understand why it doesn't.

If a int[] is allowed, it should be able to understand what the type is, right?

Comment: A Comparator's compare method is supposed to return an integer. Your lambda returns a boolean.

Comment: Tx! Looked at it way too long already :-)